# WordPress Nav won't display

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, nav

I'm attempting to make a WordPress theme from scratch for the first time. Having trouble with the  displaying. Here's what my theme [looks like](http://qwick.info/).

Here is the code:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-inner">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="brand" href="<?php echo site_url(); ?>"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a>
    <div class="nav-collapse collapse">

          <?php 

            $defaults = array(
                'container' => false,
                'theme_location' => 'primary-menu',
                'menu' => 'div'
                );

            wp_nav_menus( $defaults );

          ?>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</div>
```

With a new WordPress guy like myself, something tells me I'm missing something small, or I'm not explaining this properly.

Answer (score 0):

in your theme folder make header.php if it doesn't exist, then you add your code there.
[Here](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/wp-hierarchy.png) is list of templates wordpress follows.

Comment: That is part of header.php actually.

Comment: From the code here I cannot say what is the actual problem. Does anything from header displays ? Check active theme.